# Based on a combo box value, change refresh timers

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

In `.xaml.cs` I have the following code

```
        DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
        // Default value for auto generation
        timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5);

        timer.Start();
        timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
```

In `.xaml` I have the following combo box

```
        <ComboBox Name="RefreshTick" SelectedIndex="0" SelectionChanged="RefreshTick_Change">
            <ComboBoxItem>1</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>2</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>3</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>4</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>5</ComboBoxItem>
        </ComboBox>
```

This means that every `ItemValue` will refresh some values elsewhere every 1,2,3,4 or 5 seconds.

Under my `RefreshTick_Change` I would like to have it so whenever a `ComboBoxItem` is selected, the time for refresh changes

I have tried the following:

```
private void RefreshTick_Change(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (RefreshTick.SelectedIndex == 0)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        if (RefreshTick.SelectedIndex == 1)
        {
            return 2;
        }
        if (RefreshTick.SelectedIndex == 2)
        {
            return 3;
        }
        if (RefreshTick.SelectedIndex == 3)
        {
            return 4;
        }
        if (RefreshTick.SelectedIndex == 4)
        {
            return 5;
        }
    }
```

But clearly, `return` is not the right expression
Can anyone help? And is there a way to have it so I don't need five `if` statements one after the other?

Comment: Maybe you can try something like: timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, RefreshTick.SelectedIndex); and just call the event whenever the combo box value changes

Answer (score 2):

Try this (or something very similar):

```
private void RefreshTick_Change(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    timer.Stop();
    timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(RefreshTick.SelectedIndex + 1);
    timer.Start();
}
```

Comment: but it says `timer.Stop();` does not exist in the current context :/

Comment: Where in your code behind is timer declared?  It will need to be declared at the global scope if you want to access it within RefreshTick_Change.

Comment: It's the ` DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();` under my `public MainWindow(){ . . . .}` code

Comment: So it is both declared and defined in constructor MainWindow.  DispatchTimer timer;  It needs to be a declared at global scope (where you can also define it e.g. = new DispatchTimer().  Or you can continue to define it in MainWindow's constructor.  But it **must** be declared at global scope.

Comment: I see now; but now the values aren't refreshing at all... Am I missing something? I declare `DispatchTimer` globally, and call the `timer.Stop` etc in the `RefreshTick_Change` method

Comment: Not sure what you mean by the values aren't refreshing, but check to see if timer_Tick is being called at the proper interval.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95970/discussion-between-clay-ver-valen-and-badja).

Answer (score 1):

I would try the following in the SelectedIndexChanged event

```
timer.IsEnabled = false;
// Add timer tick event code??
timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, RefreshTick.SelectedIndex );
timer.IsEnabled = true;
```

Stop the timer, reset the interval based on the selected index, and then restart the timer.  You may want to do some code that does whatever the timer tick event did as well.

Comment: Only thing is, `timer.Stop();` "does not exist in the current context"

Comment: I'm assuming DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer(); is a class variable and can be used in the combo box change event After reading the documentation try IsEnable instead, I'll update my example.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check for null value of the timer.
Because combobox fires SelectionChanged event during startup.

```
private void RefreshTick_Change(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (timer == null) return;

            int period = Int32.Parse(((ComboBoxItem)RefreshTick.SelectedItem).Content.ToString());
            timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(period);
            timer.Stop();
            timer.Start();
        }
```